# Invoking GAE/Go Local Development Server on Gogland

Tags: google-app-engine, go, goland

How can I invoke GAE/Go local development server on Gogland?

In Run/Debug Configuration window, I have the warning "Go SDK is not specified", but I can't find how I can set Go SDK.

[image]

Even then I pressed OK, and invoked with Run -> Run 'Unnamed', I got this error.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\Gogland 171.3780.106\bin\runnerw.exe" C:/Go\bin\go.exe serve C:/path/to/app.yaml
go: unknown subcommand "serve"
Run 'go help' for usage.

Process finished with exit code 2
```

[image]

How can I fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of the error is that a regular Go distribution is used as an `SDK` (`GOROOT`).

To run GAE Go application you need to use [GAE Go SDK](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/download) as a `GOROOT`. Changing `GOROOT` is available via settings `File | Setting | Go | GOROOT`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I set GOROOT to (Go App Engine SDK Path)/goroot and it worked.

Comment: When I try to do that I get: _The selected directory is not a valid home for Go SDK_ any clues?

Comment: The issue might be related, please follow it to get updates. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-3895