# Debugging GAE/Go application on Gogland

Tags: google-app-engine, go, goland

This is the continuation of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43243820/invoking-gae-go-local-development-server-on-gogland).

I could invoke GAE/Go local development server, but I can not debug my GAE/Go application on Gogland.

Run -> Debug

Then I selected "Edit".

[image]

Then I clicked "Debug"

[image]

Then the popup below is shown.

[image]

How can I debug my GAE/Go application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging GAE apps is not currently supported, see: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-1897

Comment: I see, but I hope GAE debugging will be supported.

Comment: As you can see from the issue, GAE support for debugging is more an issue related to GAE itself rather than the IDE. Since you are on Windows, even if the IDE would use the workarounds in place for debugging GAE apps it would still not work for you so that would make it a worse experience, especially if you use Windows and other operating systems.